# Delete from multiple tables using PL/PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have 3 tables. Which I want to use a postgresql function via giving only `film_person_id` to delete related roles, films and all other remaining film people from `film_person` table.

The thing I want to do is, when I call `delete_film_person2(15);` I want to delete related roles which is `role_id : 23` and `role_id : 24` also `film_person_id : 15` and `film_person_id : 16` from `film_person` table.

here are the tables;

roles:

[image: roles]

film_person:

[image: film_person]

top_level_films:

[image: top_level_films]

here is my function

```
create or replace function delete_film_person2(int)
returns varchar
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
result varchar;
f int; 
basket_film_id int;
begin
    select top_level_film_id into basket_film_id from roles where film_person_id = $1; 
 
    for f in select film_person_id from roles where top_level_film_id = basket_film_id  
    loop 
    delete from film_person where film_person_id = f.film_person_id;
    end loop;
    result = 'success';
    return result;
end;
$$
```

but it gives error of;

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "f"
LINE 1: f.film_person_id
        ^
QUERY:  f.film_person_id
CONTEXT:  delete_film_person2(integer) PL/pgSQL fonksiyonu, 12. satır, RAISE içinde
SQL state: 42P01
```

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) not as screen shots. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

```
create or replace function delete_film_person2(p_film_person_id int)
  returns varchar
as
$$
begin
  with deleted_roles as (
    delete from roles
    where film_person_id = p_film_person_id
    returning top_level_film_id
  ), deleted_films as (
    delete from top_level_films
    where film_id in (select top_level_film_id 
                      from delete_roles)
  )
  delete from film_person
  where film_person_id = p_film_person_id;
  return 'success';
end;
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

You wouldn't even need PL/pgSQL for this.

Answer (score 0):

changed `f` variable data type and added 2 more `delete` queries

```
returns varchar
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
result varchar;
f record;
fp_people record;
basket_film_id int;
begin
    select top_level_film_id into basket_film_id from roles where film_person_id = $1; 
     
    for f in select roles.film_person_id from roles where roles.top_level_film_id = basket_film_id  
    loop 
    delete from film_person where film_person.film_person_id = f.film_person_id;
    end loop;
    delete from roles where top_level_film_id = basket_film_id;
    delete from top_level_films where film_id = basket_film_id;
    result = 'success';
    return result;
end;
$$
```